# easy program checking ip - scanf segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays, loops, scanf

I have assignment to make easy program in c which check class of IP address. My problem is that I don't work in c, and I don't know what's wrong with my program, because I don't have any IDE and everything compiles on my Debian.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int ip[4];
    int i=0;

    printf("Enter IP address: ");

    for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
        printf("%d: ",i);
        scanf("%s",ip[i]);
    }

    printf("Your IP address: %03d.%03d.%03d.%03d\n",ip[0],ip[1],ip[2],ip[3]);

    if(ip[0]>=0 && ip[0]<=127){
        printf("This is class A IP address\n");
        printf("Network address: %03d.0.0.0",ip[0]);
    }
    if(ip[0]>127 && ip[0]<=191){
        printf("This is class B IP address\n");
        printf("Network address: %03d.%03d.0.0",ip[0],ip[1]);
    }
    if(ip[0]>191 && ip[0]<224){
        printf("This is class C IP address\n");
        printf("Network address: %03d.%03d.%03d.0",ip[0],ip[1],ip[2]);
    }

    return 1;
    }
```

When I have this code there's segmentation fault and when in line 18 I made

```
scanf("%s",&ip[i]);
```

I don't have any error, but my numbers are random.

Comment: change `scanf("%s",&ip[i]);` to `scanf("%d",&ip[i]);` . ip is int array and ip[i] is of type int. "%s" is for reading string/character arrays while %d is for int

Comment: I didn.t know there is difference beetwen %s and %d, I thought this arguments just can't recur... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` requires a pointer to the memory where it shall store the result. You are not passing a pointer. You pass an array value.

Besides that you are trying to scan a string (aka %s) into an integer variable. To scan an integer use `%d`

So change

```
scanf("%s",ip[i]);
```

to

```
scanf("%d", &ip[i]);
```

Finally, you should always check the value returned by `scanf` to make sure that you got the correct number of items, i.e.

```
if (scanf("%d", &ip[i]) != 1)
{
   // Illegal input.
   // Add error handling, e.g. just terminate
   exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change line :

```
scanf("%s",ip[i]);
```

to :

```
scanf("%d", &ip[i]);   //%d instead of %s
```

as :

- The symbol `&` is necessary in order to pass a *pointer* to `scanf`.
- You want to read `int`s, so the correct specifier is `%d`. `%s` is for strings.